# how to instantiate an object inside an array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

How can i instantiate an object inside an array o object?

for example:

```
MyClass arrayOfObject[40];  // define an array of 40 objects.
```

how can i instantiate the object at[0]?

thank you.

Comment: _"how can i instantiate the object at[0]"_ - You already have.

Comment: What do you mean by instantiate?

Comment: IS to create an object.

Comment: That would be `arrayofObjects[0] = MyClass();`

Comment: Why do you think it isn't already instantiated?

Comment: When you define (or allocate) an array all the objects are instantiated automatically.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: No, that's just replacing it with another identical object.

Answer (score 0):

It is *already* instantiated, and default-constructed; this happened when the array was created. Otherwise it would be an array of... what?!

If you wish to replace it with an object that is not default-constructed, then you may:

```
arrayOfObject[0] = MyClass(x, y, z);
```

Otherwise there is nothing to do.